# How can I make pry re-cache the files from the 'load' command after it cached them the first time? Ruby

Tags: ruby, pry

Lets say I have 2 Ruby files:
**board.rb** and **card.rb**.
Inside **board.rb** I have the following code:

```
require_relative "card"
```

Now when  I run **load "board.rb"** inside PRY for the first time it loads both files in just fine, but if I make any changes to **card.rb** and load the board again, it doesn't re-cache the changes to the card. Is there any way for force cache everything again?

Comment: you mean you don't see the changes from card right?

Comment: right. I then have to type in **load "card.rb"** specifically, into pry to see the changes.

Comment: maybe something like this? https://www.seancdavis.com/blog/add-reload-method-to-ruby-console/ there seems to be no other way than calling load again on your files

Comment: Thanks, @Joel, this sure does what I intended. Another quick way I found out that reloads everything is just to quit the current PRY session and open another. The new session still remembers your old commands, AND it will also reload all your files when you load the parent file. (I wish they added like a --flag to the 'load' command to reload everything)